# Error in installing Docker Desktop Settings version is too high for the application. Use the latest version or reset to factory defaults to continue

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-desktop

I am trying to install Docker Desktop 3.2.0. I am getting this error while installing docker desktop

Settings Error

Settings version is too high for the application. Use the latest version or reset to factory defaults to continue.

My OS Version is - macOS Big Sur 11.5.2

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzJvM.png)

Comment: please check if this thread solves your issue https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4537 or revert to factory defaults if **no** important information is saved

Comment: reverting to factory defaults helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [this](http://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4537) thread they discuss changing a value in `~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json`: changing `settingsVersion` from 6 to 5

### WARNING!

Though in this case reverting to factory defaults was **successful** but should be taken with a grain of salt, unless no important information is saved this could erase vital data.

Comment: Worked for me for when downgrading and the "Reset to Factory" button did not work. Changed settingsVersion from 16 to 6.

Answer (score 2):

Go to ~/Library/Group Containers folder and delete 'group.com.docker' folder and try to install the docker again. It worked for me.